# Child's bg color overrides parent's background image

Tags: html, css

Child's bg color overrides parent's background image

I have a parent image which is required to be put as a backround of whole page.
Now if I put background color into a child div, the parent image is not visible. 
Can I somehow put background color of child behind the parent background image? Is it even possible?

Tried this one: [How to display parent's bg-image over child elements bg-color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41599594/how-to-display-parents-bg-image-over-child-elements-bg-color)

Code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KazpYM

But the solutions provided doesn't work as I need to put some text in the child div which should be visible over parent background image.

```css
.athletes{
 background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/Ytf12qW.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 -webkit-background-size: 45% 100%;
 background-size: 45% 100%;
 background-position: 14%;
}

.line{
 width: 100%;
 height: 200px;
}

.line-gray{background-color: #c1c1c1;}

.line-violet{background-color: #5e42b0;}
```

```html
<div class="athletes">
 <div class="line"></div>
 <div class="line line-gray"></div>
 <div class="line line-violet"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps they want the code here. Click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57607618/edit) then `[<>]` snippet editor and post the code here in a [mcve]

Comment: Alternatively they think it is a strange and impossible request - you can add transparency to the child but that is likely not what you meant?

Comment: @mplungjan I tried my best to keep the question neat and clean. Putting whole code snippet in the question itself will look worse. The link of the codepen has all the required snippet. And if it is an impossible request, they could have comment that as well.

Comment: I posted the snippet. Please provide a [mcve] of your issue with expected output and ignore the downvoters

Comment: Yes, I agree but I am in a minority: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes

Comment: if u dont need override give the !important mark to css

Comment: It's possible that people downvoted because this is impossible. Though I don't think that would be a good reason to downvote, but then people have been known to not downvote for good reasons.

Comment: @AdamsHales without a version of what you are trying or at least a picture of it. this question is not answerable

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the background of child elements to be transparent use rgba(x,x,x,opacity) for color. If you want to have a transparent image  on parent use ::after pseudo selector and set opacity of the element. 
Here is a working example for you.

```css
.athletes{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.athletes::after{
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
 content: "";
 background: url(https://i.imgur.com/Ytf12qW.jpg) no-repeat center center/cover;
}

.line{
 width: 100%;
 height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  color: purple;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(111,111,111,0.4)
}

.line-gray{background-color: rgba(222,222,0,0.4);}

.line-violet{background-color: rgba(127,177,0,0.4);}
```

```html
<div class="athletes">
 <div class="line">item1</div>
 <div class="line line-gray">item2</div>
 <div class="line line-violet">item3</div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps, comment this answer if something is unclear.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't solves the purpose, I wanted the background-image of parent to overlap child's background-color, but text of child should be above parent's background-image. Transparency/opacity in either of the images/colors doesn't provide what I need.

Comment: @AdamsHales then what’s the point of having background color in the children element?

Answer (score -4):

no, you can not!
you must to use background color rgba for child's background!
with parameter a, you can set opacity for colors!!!
then you can see parent background image.